# excel lookup: Partial match between two columns if not match remove one character and try

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel I have two columns A & B. A column is the original data and B column is lookup data. C column is result data.

If A is matching in B (exactly) get the value of B, if not matching exactly then remove the last character and try until it match. If there is no match even after removing character by character(repeat for entire word) then need to put NA(Not Available).

Is it possible to achieve this in excel? I tried with VLOOKUP but I didnt get exactly how to loop.

Example:

```
A                       B                  c(Result)
Samsung                 Samsung            Samsung
Samsungflexwash         honeywell          Samsung
Samsungsbf              3M                 Samsung
honeywelllyric                             honeywell


A Column:

Samsung
Samsung
Samsungflexwash
Samsungsbf
honeywelllyric
honeywelllyric

B Column:

3M
Samsung
honeywell
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a non CSE array type formula.  It gets entered normally.

It also is dynamic.  It will iterate only through those rows in column B that have a value in it.  So it will not do any un-necessary iterations and will grow or shrink depending on the number of values in column B

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",B:B)))/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",B:B)) & "*",A1,0))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Scott - Can you please explain me the formula. When I tried I was getting #NUM!. What I did is, I copied all the source data in A column and all lookup data in B column. In C column I used the formula. Please let me know If I am doing mistake.

Comment: What Excel are you using?  Older ones do not have AGGREGATE.

Answer (score 0):

Use this **array formula** at `C1` and fill down:

```
C1
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,FIND($B$1:$B$10,A1),0))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

p.s. **avoid full columns** with array formulas because it slows down. Use a reasonable number of rows in the formula. I used `B1:B10` but you can go to thousands, but don't go full `B:B`.

---

**Some explanation**

When inside an *array formula*, the expression `FIND($B$1:$B$10, A1)` will generate an array where each entry `i` is the position where the content of cell `Bi` is found in cell `A1` (#NA if not found). Then the `MATCH` function finds in this array the position where `FIND` returned `1`; because our aim is to find a cell in B that matches the start of `A1`. Finally, `INDEX` uses this position and returns the matched cell from column B.

Comment: ASH - Can you please explain me the formula. When I tried I was getting #NA. This is the one I tried "=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(MATCH(B:B&"*",A1,0)),0))" What I did is, I copied all the source data in A column and all lookup data in B column. In C column I used the formula. Please let me know If I am doing mistake